# Parseing json in php

Tags: php, json

i guys me facing a strange error following code running smoothly but since 15 days its not working and not giving error to me . whats the problem in this code and is there any other option available. i have api by which i want fatch all the record and then transfer into database . SInce its working fine but its not working, kindly check .

```
<?php

            $servername = "localhost";
                       $username = "root";
                       $password = "com";
                       $dbname = "sabk";
    $con = mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());


    mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
    $jsondata = file_get_contents('http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=e159f64e3dd49fddc3bb21dcda70f10c6670ea91aac30c7cb1d4ed37b20c45b8');
    echo "<script>console.log($jsondata);</script>";
    echo $jsondata;
    $data = json_decode($jsondata, true);


     foreach ($data as $row)
    {
        $promo_id=$row['promo_id'];
        $offer_name=$row['offer_name'];
        $coupon_title=$row['coupon_title'];
        $category=$row['category'];
        $coupon_description=$row['coupon_description'];
        $coupon_type=$row['coupon_type'];
        $coupon_code=$row['coupon_code'];
        $link=$row['link'];
        $coupon_expiry=$row['coupon_expiry'];
        $added=$row['added'];
        $store_image=$row['store_image'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Vcom(promo_id,offer_name,coupon_title,category,coupon_description,coupon_type,coupon_code,link,coupon_expiry,added,store_image)
    VALUES('$promo_id' ,'$offer_name','$coupon_title','$category','$coupon_description','$coupon_type','$coupon_code','$link','$coupon_expiry','$added','$store_image')";
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $con );

    if(!$retval)
    {
      $sql = "UPDATE Vcom SET offer_name=$offer_name,coupon_title=$coupon_title,category=$category,
      coupon_description=$coupon_description ,coupon_type=$coupon_type,coupon_code=$coupon_code,
      link=$link,coupon_expiry=$coupon_expiry,added=$added
    WHERE promo_id=$promo_id";
     mysql_query( $sql, $con );
            echo "Data Updated ".'<br>';

    }
    else
    {
        echo "Entered data successfully\n";
    }






    }
     mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: We need to know the error you're getting.

Comment: i dont get errror any its blank check output http://sabkideal.com/flipkart/vcom.php

Comment: You should use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead of doing a separate `UPDATE` query when the `INSERT` fails. You're missing lots of quotes in your `UPDATE` query.

Comment: You should also stop using the obsolete mysql extension, switch to PDO or mysqli, and use prepared statements with parameters instead of substituting strings into the SQL.

Comment: @Barmar dont receive any error on server log

Comment: When a query fails, you should print the error message: `echo mysql_error($con);`. Also, put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning of the script.

Comment: I see `<script>console.log();</script>` when I go to your page. So it's having a problem getting a response from the API, and then the script is exiting for some reason, probably because `json_decode` is failing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to display errors in the page Add:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);    
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```